# Procedimiento almacenado no inserta datos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Muy buenas compañeros, aqui vuelvo con otra duda.
Estoy creando un procedimiento que me inserte datos en una tabla 'morosos' cuando el tiempo sin devolver en libro sea superior a 30 dias, El procedimiento lo tengo creado pero no hay manera de que me haga el insert en la tabla.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE listar_morosos()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO morosos (Nombre_apellidos, Telefono, email, Titulo, ISBN, Dias)
SELECT CONCAT(nombre,' ',Apellidos), Telefono, E_mail, Titulo, ISBN, DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE()) 
FROM usuarios, libros, prestados 
WHERE DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE())>=30;
END
```

Ese es el codigo que hice para crear el procedimiento, pero al hacer el 'call' la tabla morosos sigue vacia.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda, Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la clausula **values**, que especifica los valores de una instruccion insert.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE listar_morosos()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO morosos (Nombre_apellidos, Telefono, email, Titulo, ISBN, Dias)
values (
 SELECT CONCAT(nombre,' ',Apellidos), Telefono, E_mail, Titulo, ISBN, DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE()) 
 FROM usuarios, libros, prestados 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE())>=30
);
END
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicar el intervalo de tiempo que quieres controlar con DATEDIFF.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE())>=30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que deberías validar es si la sentencia

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre,' ',Apellidos), Telefono, E_mail, Titulo, ISBN,
DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE()) 
FROM usuarios, libros, prestados 
WHERE DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE())>=30;
```

trae datos y si éstos corresponden al mismo tipo de datos de la tabla de destino

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema en el orden de las fechas, `DATEDIFF(fecha_pres, CURRENT_DATE())` te 
retornará una cantidad de días negativos, ya que estás restando una fecha menor a una mayor, por lo que nunca será mayor a 30.

Prueba hacerlo así:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), fecha_pres)>=30;
```

Comment: GRACIAS!! llevaba un montón de tiempo dandole vueltas. Es logico, al valor mayor se le resta el menos, en este caso el mayor es la fecha de hoy.